# How to set do...while for a node iteration

Tags: java, graph, while-loop, do-loops

my target is to iterate the node searching logic that I have created. For doing this, I've implemented a do...while condition. In do{} i say "choose the action that satisfy the precondition with the lower cost" from an initial state and initial node. When it is found, set the initial state and node with the new ones. 
In while() I express the condition "until the state is equal to the goal state" go ahead.

The problem is that when I run this, is printing only the result of the first iteration but seems that is still continuing to compute no stop.

This is the code

```
private static Node nodeStatus;

static  Action loadPlaneP1 = new Action("loadPlaneP1",pkg1Location[1], pkg2Location[0], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0], 30);
static  Action loadPlaneP2 = new Action("loadPlaneP2", pkg1Location[0], pkg2Location[1], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0], 40);
....//other actions



 State state = new State(0, pkg1Location[0], pkg2Location[0], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0]);
 State newState = new State(0, pkg1Location[0], pkg2Location[0], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0]);
 static State goal = new State(0, pkg1Location[5], pkg2Location[4], truckLocation[3], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1]);

 static Action[] acts = {loadPlaneP1, loadPlaneP2, fly, unloadPlaneP1, unloadPlaneP2, loadTruckP1, loadTruckP2, drive, unloadTruckP1, unloadTruckP2 };

Node startNode = new Node(state, 0);

int[] costs = {loadPlaneP1.getActionCost(), loadPlaneP2.getActionCost(), fly.getActionCost(), unloadPlaneP1.getActionCost(), unloadPlaneP2.getActionCost(), loadTruckP1.getActionCost(), loadTruckP2.getActionCost(), drive.getActionCost(), unloadTruckP1.getActionCost(),unloadTruckP2.getActionCost()};      



 do{

         if(nodeStatus != startNode) {
               nodeStatus = startNode;
            }
             else {
               nodeStatus = startNode;
                  }


         if(nodeStatus == startNode) {


         System.out.println("Old state parameters are " + "pkg1Location: " + state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " + state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ state.getStateParameter5());




            for(int i = 0; i < acts.length; i++) {


                if(acts[i].getActionCost() == getMinValue(costs)) {

                   System.out.println("PRE The first parameter is : " + acts[i].getActParameter1() + acts[i].name +" "+ acts[i].actionCost);



                      if(acts[i].loadPlaneP1Precondition() == true) {

                          System.out.println("POST The first parameter is : " + acts[i].getActParameter1());
                          System.out.println("Precondition satysfied" + " with action name: " + acts[i].name);

                      if(acts[i].getActParameter1() != state.getStateParameter1()) {

                          newState.setStateParameter1(acts[i].getActParameter1());
                         }

                      if(acts[i].getActParameter2() != state.getStateParameter2()) {
                         if(acts[i].getActParameter2() != State.pkg2Location[1]) {

                         newState.setStateParameter2(acts[i].getActParameter2());
                            } 
                         }

                      if(acts[i].getActParameter3() != state.getStateParameter3()) {

                         newState.setStateParameter3(acts[i].getActParameter3());
                         }

                      if(acts[i].getActParameter4() != state.getStateParameter4()) {

                         newState.setStateParameter4(acts[i].getActParameter4());
                         }

                      if(acts[i].getActParameter5() != state.getStateParameter5()) {

                         newState.setStateParameter5(acts[i].getActParameter5());
                         }

                         acts[i].setActCost(100);
            } 

               ................................//checking other preconditions



            Node child = new Node("Node "+ i, newState, startNode, acts[i].getActionCost(), acts[i].name);



            startNode = child;
            state = newState;




            System.out.println("Costs array: "+  Arrays.toString(costs));
            System.out.println("ActionID" +" " +  i);
            System.out.println("The action choosen is " + acts[i].name +" "+ acts[i].actionCost +" "+ acts[i].getActParameter1());
            System.out.println("State parameters updated are " + "pkg1Location: " + state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " + state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ state.getStateParameter5());
            System.out.println("The node created is : " + child.getNodeName());
                }


            }


        }



    }while(state == goal);
```

How can I print the result for each iteration?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Beyond that: please take the time to nicely format/indent all of your code. You want others to spend their free time to help you with your problem, so you please spend the 5 minutes it takes to come up with nicely human readable input.

Comment: I have updated the code identation and reduced the code, what else is needed? Thanks

Comment: It's still not reproduce-able. What is nodeStatus,for example.

Comment: I have added all the parameters definition

Comment: Sorry, you still have plenty of useless newlines in there, and your indenting further down is still pretty much messed up. And as said: please read that link: we need to be able understand the whole path that leads to your problem. We have for example **zero** information about the example data your code fails on. Again: please read that link I gave you. Carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your loop, you're checking `while(state == goal)`.
Try something like `while (state.equals(goal));`.

You should use the `equals` method when comparing object instances (except when they're enumerations, which is not your case it seems).

By the way, you said **"until the state is equal to the goal state" go ahead**.
This would be translated into `while (!state.equals(goal));` (not equal).

**UPDATE:**
Furthermore, in the beginning of your loop, you have the following code:

```
if(nodeStatus != startNode) {
               nodeStatus = startNode;
            }
             else {
               nodeStatus = startNode;
                  }


         if(nodeStatus == startNode) {
```

First of all, also here you're comparing 2 objects by means of the equals sign instead of the equals method.
Furthermore, in either case you assign `startNode` to `nodeStatus`. The if-condition afterwards will always be true.

Comment: Great catch. The power of groups is amazing.

Comment: If I write like while `(!state.equals(goal));` is never satisfying the precondition and repeat no stop the printed result  of `System.out.println("Old state parameters are " + "pkg1Location: " + state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " + state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ state.getStateParameter5());`

Comment: Did you implement the method `State.equals()`? Otherwise, it's like using the equals sign.

Comment: I've seen it thanks. I have updated the equals method. The meaning of that part is when you start `node status` is equal to `startNode` and after the first iteration, due to `startNode` is updating, reset also `nodeStatus` with the new value

Comment: But I receive the same result of before like this

Comment: Your code is far from complete. I'm missing the implementation of the classes `Node`, `Action` and `State`. What are the variables `pkg1Location`, `truckLocation`, etc.?

Comment: I know, it's a bit long and for this reason I didn't posted everything. Anyway I solved something thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You should try the solution of Robert Kock.

You need to check:

1. If State class is created by you , you should override the equals method(so you aren't comparing the addresses of the objects).
2. And follow the solution of Robert Kock `while (!state.equals(goal));`